# Running sed command from ansible

Tags: shell, ansible, command, line

I'm trying to update a few .sql files and had success using sed in the command line but I cannot get it to work from ansible.

The command goes something like:

1. cd /tmp/Ratings_DB
2. Run the command as sudo - sudo sed -i 's/TYPE/ENGINE/' *.sql
3. The files are created from root account hence sudo.

My goal is to replace `TYPE` with `ENGINE` as they are older .sql dumps. Unless there is a way to do with directly in MySQL - I cannot import them.

> Error
>   'An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/jesse/Desktop/playbooks/cd /tmp/Ratings_DB'

Seems I'm not redirecting to the correct directory somehow.

Comment: Can you post a code sample?

Answer (score 10):

You dont have to make 'cd', you can refer directly to the filename. Also, its better to use 'become=true' instead of using sudo:

```
---
- name: pb
  hosts: localhost
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: replace in sql files
      shell: sed -i 's/TYPE/ENGINE/' /tmp/*.sql
```

run playbook as:

> $ ansible-playbook pb.yml -e "ansible_sudo_pass=1234"

Comment: There is a better approach using line-in-file module. but the question is about running sed within ansible.

Comment: please accept the answer if you are satisfied, thanks .

Answer (score 8):

Better use replace or lineinfile module rather than generic sed .

eg.

```
- replace:
path: /etc/hosts
regexp: '(\s+)old\.host\.name(\s+.*)?$'
replace: '\1new.host.name\2'
backup: yes
```

Comment: This is a nice answer, but it's not easy to see how you could translate from the sed example in the question to this regex example (which is unrelated). Could you please update the answer to either use the example from the question, or add a note explaining the equivalent sed command to your answer?